# Is it possible to make an interface method accept different classes C#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

Hi I was wondering if there is any nice way without an overkill to have an interface method, that could take in for example 3 different models? I'm looking for something like this:

```
 public interface IOperations 
    {
        void AddTranslation(TranslationLocationEnum Location, T model)               
    }

 public class ApplicationOne : IOperations
   {
        public void AddTranslation(TranslationLocationEnum Location, ClassType1 model)     
   }

 public class ApplicationTwo : IOperations
   {
        public void AddTranslation(TranslationLocationEnum Location, ClassType2 model)     
   }
```

Thank you

Comment: You can make it generic (`IOperations<T>`) but then you can have problem using (calling) it. How is that interface supposed to be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface IOperations<T> where T : class
{
    void AddTranslation(TranslationLocationEnum Location, T model);
}

public class ApplicationOne : IOperations<ApplicationOne>
{
    public void AddTranslation(TranslationLocationEnum Location, ApplicationOne model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ApplicationTwo : IOperations<ApplicationTwo>
{
    public void AddTranslation(TranslationLocationEnum Location, ApplicationTwo model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Use generic interface and pass type at the time of inheriting the interface. Hope this helps.

Comment: That would be: `public class ApplicationOne : IOperations<ClassType1>`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, you can pass any class. I just gave an example.

Comment: Okay it would be working like this, but what if I need to pass multiple types of models eg:
I have an AddTranslationApplication1 ,AddTranslationApplication2 class and also have an EditTranslationApp1, EditTranslationApp2 class.
If i go with this sollution it means I have to create an interface for every operation in my understanding. I would just like to have an interface with add/edit/read operations each accepting 3x3 different classess(and i dont want to do this: where T : class, where Z: class etc

Comment: You don't need to create an interface for every model, just create one generic intreface with your add/edit/delete method definition and at the time of inheriting pass the model type and implement the add/edit/delete method. Feel free to ask if stuck anywhere. I will be happy to help.

Comment: I feel that you want repository pattern for add update delete. Try this blog http://blog.falafel.com/implement-step-step-generic-repository-pattern-c/

Comment: Thank you, but what i mean was i have this interface operations:

void add( anyClass )
void edit( anyClass )

and then i would have a repository lets say application1 and application2.

Application1 uses an AddTranslationType1 and EditTranslationType1 class
Application2 uses an EditTranslationType1 and EditTranslationType2 class
So if i try App1Repository : IOperations<AddTranslation1> then my edit translation class cannot be used. I've seen people doing where T : class, Z : class, X : class but I dont like the idea. I'm not sure if i was clear enough